# Module not found for metrics within skimage. Everything else is ok

Tags: python, image-processing, conda, scikit-image

I keep getting `No module named 'skimage.metrics'` only for "metrics" everything else works fine.
Is it deprecated? I have been unable to do anything and documentations doesn't mention anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of skimage is 0.17.0 and it has skimage.metrics.
https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.metrics.html

It is also in 0.16.0
https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.16.x/api/api.html

It is NOT in 0.15.0
https://scikit-image.org/docs/0.15.x/api/api.html

So 16 and later should have it. You can install the 0.16.1 version with:

```
pip install scikit-learn==0.16.1
```

Comment: This page list api changes and shows metrics appearing in 16.  https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api_changes.html

Comment: Thank you! I had the 0.15.0, I just updated!
Thank you again!